# Rails - Where (directories) to put Models that are not Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, service-object

We are building out apps that have Models that are not database components.
We are curious to learn what others are doing in the rails community to address this subject.

We are struggling with where to put them.

Should we have:

```
app/models/domain
```

or

```
app/domain/models
```

or perhaps

```
app/models   # Business Models
app/models/ar # Active Record Models
```

or perhaps

```
app/models/domain/   # Business Models
app/models/domain/ar # Active Record Models
```

Part of this is that we are struggling with how close to be to rails standards and how much to create a structure that will be good for what we need.

If we think of the objects as Service Objects, we could have

```
app/models/service-object
```

and

```
app/models/ # For plain active record
```

Another route to go down is not have stuff within app, e.g.

```
/service_objects
```

instead of

```
/app/models/service_objects
```

Presumably if we want access via a rails app we're better of using app/ in order to take advantage of convention over configuration.

Comment: The directory is called "models". It's not called "active_record descendants only". I just put them together and throw Mongoid models on top :)

Comment: You could place them under `lib` if you really want to stick with AR-only in models

Comment: I'd reconsider sticking them in `lib` but its still an option. I like to stick files in lib that I'd consider good candidates for extracting into gems for re-use.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In my experience, the division of where you put these models comes down to what they functionally represent in the specific context of your application.

I usually reserve `app/models` for resource based models. If that model represents a resource that is instantiated and manipulated by your application it goes here. Doesn't need to be AR or db backed.

If the model serves a consistent functionality but varies on the parameters, I give them a top level dir in app. Such as `app/mailers` `app/observers` etc. However, if you have one resource that requires an observer, it might not make sense to have an `app/observers` dir with just one file in it.

Everything else goes in `lib`. There are a few reasons why this is preferable.

1. You can choose when to require the files in `lib`. You can be much more selective about which files get loaded when your app starts. If you put everything in `app/models` you've got no granularity over what gets loaded.
2. Namespacing your models as your app grows is easier in lib. Sure you can namespace in `app/models` but several layers of nesting in `app/models` always ends up nasty. It's best to keep the namespacing in `lib`.
3. Housekeeping is made much easier when you've got things in their functionally correct place. It's not a resource? It's not an observer? Must be in `lib`. The whole reason you're putting thought into this up front is to provide discoverability to developers down the line.

Answer (score 14):

For service objects you'll usually have them directly under the app directory `app/services/`. Workers and serializers also follow this pattern `app/workers/` `app/serializers/`. As for your models that are not AR you can still stick them in the models directory. That's just my take on it.

Comment: +1 That is useful, thanks.  We're a little bit concerned that as the application grows we might end up with 34 Active Record models and 12 Non-Active Record ones and that then models would have a mish-mash of 46 together.  That might be ok, we're just wondering about that potential future also.

Comment: Agree with this - at a certain point, if you have stable non-AR models that fit into specific functions, you can always extract them into Modules.

Comment: Well it also comes down to separating concerns by applications. You don't want a single application to get so big that you can't manage it. For example, when an app gets too big, I'd consider separating auth into its own application and follow that pattern then just communicate through APIs.

Answer (score 11):

If they are models, you should put them into `app/models` since this directory is meant for models and not just ActiveRecord subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

If you have classes that are not models, for instance they perhaps represent a form, I'd say go ahead and put them in `lib`.

If they are orthogonal to your application, ie: it's some interface used to call another application, you might wrap it up as a private or public gem depending on its applicability to the rest of the community.

In the end, it doesn't really matter.  Pick one thing, and agree on it with the rest of your team.  Moving things around should be pretty easy, especially if you add whatever you decide on using to the load path for your application (`$LOAD_PATH += '...'`).